# Navigator share not working in chrome desktop in mac os any alternative?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried navigator.canshare also but it's working in chrome desktop. It is giving undefined.

```
if (navigator.share) {
    navigator.share({
        title: 'Lot Quality Report',
        text: 'Lot Link -',
        url: 'https://www.google.com'
    })
        .then(() => console.log('Successful share')) //this is for sucess
            .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
  } else {
    console.log('Share not supported on this browser, do it the old way.');
    alert('Share not supported on this browser, do it the old way.');
}
```

This code is not working on google chrome desktop in mac os. Any alternative I can use to run share functionality on google chrome desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the answer, in mac os we need to change the settings of browser . Url - https://winaero.com/chrome-to-get-web-share-api-support-on-desktop/

Click on - chrome://flags/#web-share >> enable >> relaunch browser